# Visual Studio Code has type not accessible errors for new Java module

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, javafx

A newly created Java module, that is also a project in the Gradle project, is not listed as a “Project and External Dependencies”.  The Gradle project builds and appears to run for a command line gradle build (power shell, cygwin).  In Visual Studio Code, the dependent Java Project shows “type is not accessible” messages.

The problem code is at https://github.com/pnambic/depanfx

- branch `base`: working starter code
- branch `leeca/workspace`: works from gradle, VSC complains of not accessible types.

I’ve worked with Java and Gradle for years, and I thought I was getting comfortable with Visual Studio Code.  I have the Extension Pack for Java and Gradle for Java extension installed.  I’m new to Java modules and Java FX, but this feels like a gap in my understanding of Gradle projects or Visual Studio Code’s dependency construction.

I’m starting to port a desktop application into JavaFX.  The construction of the initial application structure closely followed the steps outlined under JavaFX and Visual Studio Code for the Modular with Gradle structure.  The code has a fairly conventional structure.

```
  com.pnambic.depanfx.app
    DepanFxApp - main class, launches FX
    DepanFxController - menu controller
```

Per the outline, this starter subproject defines a base module (“depanfx.app”) that requires a few javafx libraries.  It appears to work fine, and I learned a bit about Java modules and JavaFX.  This version of the application is the current base branch.

The next step is to add a new module, this one for the workspace model.  This one has a few more classes, but everything is tucked into a few packages.

```
  com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace - visible types and factory
  com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace.basic - implementation model
  com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace.gui - visible types, open for reflection
```

The module-info.java file for the new component allows JavaFX to access the gui package, and both the base package and the gui subpackage are exported.

```
module depanfx.workspace {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace.gui to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace;
    exports com.pnambic.depanfx.workspace.gui;
}
```

To use this, there were two changes in the DepanFX Java project beyond a few tweeks to the Java and FXML files.

- Add the module dependency “requires depanfx.workspace;” to the DepanFxApp module-info.java file
- Add the gradle dependency “implementation project(':DepanFxWorkspace') to the DepanFxApp build.gradle file

This code is available as the branch `leeca/workspace`.

The one clue I've stumbled upon is a difference in the dependencies as shown in the VSC sidepanel panes.

I can see in the GRADLE PROJECTS pane that the Gradle Dependencies include the new module

[Gradle projects showing dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y535Z.png)

In the JAVA PROJECTS pane, there is no evidence at all of the DepanFxWorkspace component.

[Java projects showing no dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leaT5.png)

But no amount or workspace refresh or other resets seem to convince VSC that the components in the workspace module are visible in the original app project.

I've tried Clean Java Language Server Workspace, shutting down and restarting VSC, and most of the other refresh tricks I've been able to discover.

Comment: What types are not accessible?  Presumably, it is a compile error.  What is the compile output?  Can you place it in the question as text, formatted as code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of [Extension Pack for JavaPreview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)
 and [Gradle for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-gradle) extensions installed. You can clean and build the project by executing the command `gradle clean build`.
Also, verify that the project's Java source files and module definition files are correct.

Comment: This is a recent installation of VSC, with new extensions all around.  The obvious version numbers are

Windows 10 Pro/22H2

from VSC: Version: 1.78.2 (system setup)
Commit: b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
Date: 2023-05-10T14:39:26.248Z
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: Yes; 

Extension Pack for Java is v0.25.11; Gradle for Java is v3.12.17